# What gives Rose this specific power?

Tags: vampire-academy-2022

In the new Peacock series 'Vampire Academy' Lissa and Rose share a specific bond because Lissa revived Rose from the dead due to which Rose is able to sense whenever something bad happens with Lissa. Rose also has one additional power of sensing Strigois when they are near. How does she get this power to sense Strigois if they are near her?